# Calender not shown

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

HTML

```
<form id="Create Schedule" class="form-horizontal">
    <div class="control-group">
        <label class="control-label">Date:</label>
        <div class="input-group date" class="controls">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="dateSchedule" readonly>
            <span class="input-group-addon">
                            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></i>
                            </span>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

JS

```
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: Is jQuery loaded? Is the datepicker library included after jQuery? Is code running after the element is available in DOM?

Comment: `.datepicker is not a function` you probably didnt include script

Comment: Did you include jQuery.js before datepicker js lib? plz, paste the code too.

Answer (score 0):

try to init it page load like so...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.input-group.date').datepicker({
        keyboardNavigation: false,
        format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
        autoclose: true,
        todayHighlight: true
    });
});
```

Comment: TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function
$('.input-group.date').datepicker({     I'm using Bootstrap 3.3

Comment: Make sure your Jquery is loaded before your datepicker library, and your init after.

Comment: please be sure that datepicker library loaded properly.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put your datepicker on the input tag.

try it :

```
$('#dateShedule').datepicker({
    keyboardNavigation: false,
    format: "yyyy/mm/dd",
    autoclose: true,
    todayHighlight: true
});
```

Comment: Same Error: 
 
TypeError: $(...).datepicker is not a function $('.input-group.date').datepicker({ I'm using Bootstrap 3.3

Comment: This error mean your script doesn't found the datepicker library. 
Check your import directives. 
You have to import jQuery first, then datepicker.